# (discord bot) How would I make the member count and the bot count (added up) display on the bot statues

Tags: discord.js

I have the bot statues working, but I don't know how to make it say how many members are in my server. So members and bots added together. (example: 56 members in the server! I want the number to be the member count of the server.

Comment: Hi lewis1063, there are a few issues with your question which might make it unlikely to be answered; firstly it's not immediately clear that you're asking a question about a Discord bot, and secondly it's not obvious which bit of the solution you're stuck on. Try including some more detail on what you've already done - for instance, if you already know how to display the status but you aren't sure how to get the member count, then your question is much narrower and will be far more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: As Ade said, you should post your attempts and what went wrong with them. That being said, you should know that the status for your discord bot is global, you cannot have a status for each server.

Comment: Is this bot on one server only, or multiple?

Comment: Only one @Axium

Answer (score 0):

This should work if it’s one server ONLY.

Member Count:
`var memberCount = (guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size).toString() + ‘ Members’;`

Setting Status:
`bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: memberCount}});`